# Microsoft Power-Automate Select operation does not work as intended

Tags: json, power-automate

I've got a Select-Operation on an an object that contains one key more than once.
It's practically two versions of one object in one JSON object.
I want to get the id of both of those Objects.
When i inspect the Object, i can clearly see the two different Id's, but the Select-Operation returns only one of them twice.
This is the original Object:

```
[
  {
    "Created": "2020-06-05T11:47:42",
    "ID": 9,
  },
  {
    "Created": "2020-06-05T11:06:04",
    "ID": 10,
  }
]
```

The Select-Operation looks like this:

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "from": "@body('Rest')?['value']",
        "select": {
            "ID": "@triggerBody()?['ID']",
            "Created": "@triggerBody()?['Created']"
        }
    }
}
```

And it returns:

```
[
  {
    "Created": "2020-06-05T11:47:42",
    "ID": 9,
  },
  {
    "Created": "2020-06-05T11:47:42",
    "ID": 9,
  }
]
```

I don't really understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"select": {
            "ID": "@triggerBody()?['ID']",
            "Created": "@triggerBody()?['Created']"
        }
```

is wrong, it should select item()?['ID']